# Is there a way in eclipse to select a region and shift the indentation level of all ines in that region

Tags: eclipse, indentation

Is there a way in eclipse to select a region and shift the indentation level of all lines in that region?

Note that I'm not talking about changing the formatting styles for anything, but just to be able to shift the lines I select.

I'm working with some tools that use indentation levels instead of brackets and parens and i often need to do this.   But I can't use anything like a "pretty printer" (which is what the standard Eclipse stuff really is) because such things have to understand the language in use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Select desired lines and press "TAB" key.  Should move all forward one tab.  Reverse works with Shift-"TAB" keys.